# What is apt/dpkg equivalent of redhat 'rpm -ql' in debian?

Tags: debian, apt, yum, rpm, dpkg

I would like to see the tree of the apt installed package in Debian.
I use `rmp -ql` in RedHat base linux.
What command I must use in debian?

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent is `dpkg -L` for installed packages.

You can also see the contents of non-installed packages with `apt-file list`.

You’ll find the answer to similar questions in [the Arch Linux Pacman rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta).